# Using App Script to Replace Cell Color With Value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have been using this Script since couple of month and its working fine but now the problem is i need to pull multiple column like `Col, Col2, Col5, Col7, Col11 and so on`. But this function is not working when i added a Multiple column then it stop working and throwing an error `=SAMPLE(DATA!S3:S&DATA!M3:M,"DATA!S3:S&DATA!M3:M",D3:D)`

I would appreciate your help in this regard.

```
function SAMPLE(srcValues, srcRange, dstValues) {
const srcBackgrounds = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange(srcRange).getBackgrounds();
return srcValues.map((r, i) => r.map((c, j) => {
if (dstValues[i][0] != "") {
if (srcBackgrounds[i][j] == "#f4cccc") {
return "MISSING";
}
if (srcBackgrounds[i][j] == "#b7e1cd") {
return "COMPLETE";
}
return c == "P" || c == "p" ? "Pending" : "";
}
return "";
}));
}
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand the relationship between `but now the problem is i need to pull multiple column like Col, Col2, Col5, Col7, Col11 and so on.` and your showing script. Can I ask you about the detail of the current issue of your script and your goal?

Comment: Hey thank you for being there because you are the one who created above this script. Let me explain it, the above script is Extracting a range But now what i want is to pull the columns dynamically, not in a single range like `A3:G` I want to pull columns like a `Query( A3:G, Select Col, Col2, Col5, Col7, Col11")`, Because current function cannot pull specific columns

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `BBut now what i want is to pull the columns dynamically, not in a single range like A3:G I want to pull columns like a Query( A3:G, Select Col, Col2, Col5, Col7, Col11"), Because current function cannot pull specific columns`. What is `Query( A3:G, Select Col, Col2, Col5, Col7, Col11")`? Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: I apologize that I am trying to correctly undrstand your question.

Comment: I do apologize that i am unable to elaborate my problem. Alright let me share a Example Sheet with [Link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13XzDa5HzxPy_bCa98_4SkEqXKUgUNKXjc81F2x6i3x8/edit?usp=sharing) Here i want to pull specfic columns formatting to result Sheet how i can do this using above script.

Comment: Thank you for replying and providing the sample Spreadsheet. I could see your sample Spreadsheet. But, unfortunately, I cannot understand `i want to oull specfic column formatting to result Sheet`. I apologize for my very poor English skill. For example, can you provide the sample input and output values you expect using your sample Spreadsheet?

Comment: Give me moment Sir i will provide samples

Comment: Thank you for replying. I will wait for it.

Comment: Sir i have added a sample for you in the sheet. I have used formula for each column separatly in the Result sheet can we do these steps in single formula.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your question, I propsoed a modified script as an answer. Please confirm it. In this case, please put a custom function like `=SAMPLE2("Data",Data!A2:A,"24,2,11,4,18,6")` into a cell when your provided Spreadsheet is used. If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your situation, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Spreadsheet. When you use this script, please put a custom function of `=SAMPLE2("Data",Data!A2:A,"24,2,11,4,18,6",2)`. By this, the result values are returned. In this case, from your sample Spreadsheet, `"24,2,11,4,18,6"` means Col23 Col1 Col10 Col3 Col17 Col6. Because the 1st column is `ID` in your Spreadsheet. And, the last argument of `2` means the 1st row. In your situation, the 1st row of the data is row 2. So, 2 is used. Please be careful about this.

```js
function SAMPLE2(sheetName, dstValues, columns, startRow) {
  columns = columns.split(",").map(e => Number(e.trim()));
  const range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName).getDataRange();
  const srcBackgrounds = range.getBackgrounds();
  const values = range.getValues();
  if (startRow > 1) {
    srcBackgrounds.splice(0, startRow - 1);
    values.splice(0, startRow - 1);
  }
  return values.map((r, i) => columns.map(col => {
    const j = col - 1;
    const c = r[j];
    if (dstValues[i][0] != "") {
      if (srcBackgrounds[i][j] == "#f4cccc") {
        return "MISSING";
      }
      if (srcBackgrounds[i][j] == "#b7e1cd") {
        return "COMPLETE";
      }
      return c == "P" || c == "p" ? "Pending" : "";
    }
    return "";
  }));
}
```

- In this modification, in order to use the specific columns, all data range is used. So, `sheetName` is used.

#### Reference:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

### Added:

As another approach, how about the following sample script? In this sample sript, please put a custom function like `=SAMPLE3("Data","Data!A2:A","24,2,11,4,18,6")`. By using `"Data!A2:A"` as the string value, the 1st row is retrieved from it.

#### Sample script:

```js
function SAMPLE3(sheetName, dstRange, columns) {
  columns = columns.split(",").map(e => Number(e.trim()));
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const dstRangeObj = ss.getRange(dstRange);
  const dstValues = dstRangeObj.getValues();
  const srcRange = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName).getDataRange();
  const srcBackgrounds = srcRange.getBackgrounds();
  const values = srcRange.getValues();
  const startRow = dstRangeObj.getRow();
  if (startRow > 1) {
    srcBackgrounds.splice(0, startRow - 1);
    values.splice(0, startRow - 1);
  }
  return values.map((r, i) => columns.map(col => {
    const j = col - 1;
    const c = r[j];
    if (dstValues[i][0] != "") {
      if (srcBackgrounds[i][j] == "#f4cccc") {
        return "MISSING";
      }
      if (srcBackgrounds[i][j] == "#b7e1cd") {
        return "COMPLETE";
      }
      return c == "P" || c == "p" ? "Pending" : "";
    }
    return "";
  }));
}
```

Comment: There is just one issue that why the first row is balnk where formula is being pasted.

Comment: @HSHO Thank you for replying. About `There is just one issue that why the first row is balnk where formula is being pasted.`, I updated my answer. Please confirm it. In that case, please put a custom function like `=SAMPLE2("Data",Data!A2:A,"24,2,11,4,18,6",2)` in to a cell.

Comment: @HSHO Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. As another approach, I added one more sample script. Please confirm it. In that case, the number of arguments is reduced by using `"Data!A2:A"` as the string value.